# Questions about an Android Tutorial

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I started learning about Bitmaps and simple graphics in Android. I'm a little new to this so I'm still trying to grasp the concepts. My code below comes from a tutorial. It works with bitmap and drawable. I got it to display an image of a triangle. But I have a couple of questions: First: The image of the triangle displays - but its base stretches to the bottom of the screen. How do I fix this? Second: how do I display the triangle at the center of the screen?

My code (taken from vogella.com):

Class for drawable:

```
public class MyRoundCornerDrawable extends Drawable {

private Paint paint;

public MyRoundCornerDrawable(Bitmap bitmap){
    BitmapShader shader;
    shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    int height = getBounds().height();
    int width = getBounds().width();
     RectF rect = new RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 15, 15, paint);

}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {

    return 255;
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {


}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter arg0) {


}
```

}

The MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    InputStream resource = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.triangle);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(resource);
    button.setBackground(new MyRoundCornerDrawable(bitmap));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

And XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/image"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:contentDescription="TODO" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add a `scaleType` for your `ImageView`. `fitXY` or `center` should do the trick
2. add `layout_centerInParent="true"` to your `ImageView`

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       layout_centerInParent="true" 
       android:contentDescription="TODO" />
   ```

Comment: Questions about scaleType: What is the proper syntax (I used: button.setScaleType(scaleType); - this doesn't work). And where should I place it? I placed it in onCreate.

Comment: ok. but what about scaleType? Just using layout_centerInParent makes no difference.